# Automatic loading of voices for AVSpeech​Synthesizer

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, voice, avspeechsynthesizer

Is it possible to auto-load a new speech synthesis voice within an iOS app? Several high-quality "enhanced" voices are available for download in `Settings > Accessibility > Spoken Content > Voices > English`. I would like to make use of one of the high-quality ones but do not want to have to explain to the app user that they must manually download them by navigating deep within Settings.

The Siri voices seem to be the high quality only ones that come pre-installed on my phone and unfortunately Apple does not let us use those in AVSpeech​Synthesizer. (Selecting one of those as the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice—for example

```
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "This is a test.")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: "com.apple.ttsbundle.siri_female_en-US_premium")
speechSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

has no effect; the default voice, which is lower quality, is used instead.)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. The best thing I can do at the moment is to offer to launch Settings and ask them to type "voices" in the search field to find it easily.

Comment: FYI, I have sent feedback to Apple to ask for programmatically triggering a download of a AVSpeechSynthesizer voice - after confirmation by the user. FB11424762